# possible to get the value from json output without javascript?

Tags: html, json, google-sheets

is it possible to get the value of "$t" in this url without even using javascript?

[google sheet url link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/default/public/basic/R2C1?alt=json)

what i wanted to see in my browser is: `12-Jan-2019`

not this:

```
{
  "version":"1.0",
  "encoding":"UTF-8",
  "entry":{
    "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
    "xmlns$batch":"http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch",
    "xmlns$gs":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
    "id":{
      "$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/default/public/basic/R2C1"
    },
    "updated":{
      "$t":"2019-01-17T01:51:01.318Z"
    },
    "category":[
      {
        "scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
        "term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"
      }
    ],
    "title":{
      "type":"text",
      "$t":"A2"
    },
    "content":{
      "type":"text",
      "$t":"12-Jan-2019"
    },
    "link":[
      {
        "rel":"self",
        "type":"application/atom+xml",
        "href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/default/public/basic/R2C1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: *JSON (**JavaScript Object Notation**) is a lightweight data-interchange format*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `12-Jan-2019` from the spreadsheet of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/default/public/basic/R2C1?alt=json`

If my understanding is correct, how about these endpoints?

- From your question, it is found the following values.

  - File ID of Spreadsheet is `1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8`
  - The required value is put in "A2".
- I think that the sheet ID might be 0.

#### Endpoint 1:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/pubhtml/sheet?gid=0&range=A2
```

##### Result

`12-Jan-2019` is shown at browser.

#### Endpoint 2:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/gviz/tq?gid=0&tqx=out:csv&range=A2
```

##### Result:

A CSV file including `"12-Jan-2019"` is created.

### Edit:

How about this? In this modification, `<object>` and the endpoint 1 were used.

```html
<object data="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8fyL5Nynv1Q171qyzh450_WjJGp35f9T5OYGfCQwr8/pubhtml/sheet?gid=0&range=A2" width="115" height="20">This cannot be displayed.</object>
```

#### Reference:

- [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you so much for helping me out. Sorry if my question is unclear. what i really wanted is to get to the Endpoint 1: `12-Jan-2019` as a string or text (*if it is possible*).

aside from that, how did you do this queries(`&tqx=out:csv&range=A2`)? im kinda lost in google's documentation.

Comment: @Jaeyson Anthony Y. Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I create such endpoint, I check [this document](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source). And I would like to understand correctly your question. For example, how about "Endpoint 2"?

Comment: sorry if im having a trouble visualizing the problem.
i wanted like this in html: `<div><Endpoint 1 output value></div>`.
is this possible without using javascript?